# How to properly format a replyTo message using Microsoft Bot SDK?

Tags: c#, botframework

I want create a reply message which is properly formatted(like in Skype: [image])

I tried to manually specify a `ReplyToId` but it doesn't work as I want.

```
            IMessageActivity reply = context.MakeMessage();

            string answerUrl = null;
            if (context.ConversationData.TryGetValue(KEY_ANSWER_PICTURE_URL, out answerUrl))
            {
                reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment> { new Attachment("image/png", answerUrl) };
            }

            reply.Text = "> " + question + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                                "Answer: " + Environment.NewLine + answer;

            reply.ReplyToId = questionId.ToString();

            await context.PostAsync(reply);
```

Is it possible at all? Maybe it is a channel specific feature?

**UPDATE**

The idea is to post some question(like quiz) and sometimes later I would like to  post an answer to the previous question including the question's text.

It mostly for Skype channel.

Comment: Do you want to add newlines in reply message? Which channel are you using now?

Comment: @FeiHan Actually, I don't much care about newlines. My bot posts some question and sometimes later I would like to the post an answer to previous question including the question's text. It mostly for Skype channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but there is no feature in the framework to include a previous message like you mentioned.

`ReplyToId` is a technical field used to follow the conversation but there is nothing on the channel side to manage what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to answer to question sent earlier.

What i would suggest is, store the question in UserData of Bot context and later post an answer to the question with any way you want to. Hero cards etc..

Comment: I've already implemented the logic. My question is how to properly format the reply in order to have quotes in Skype channel.